# Get a user ID from Google Play Services?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Is there any way that we can get a Google Play ID (number, string, whatever) from a particular user when utilizing Google Play Services?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For Google Play Game Services you can use:

```
String playerId = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId(getApiClient());
```

Comment: I figured it out, but thanks. This could be helpful to others in the future.

Comment: @Pygmalion is it unique and constant? Can it be used for saving player's progress online?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the service you are trying to access. 
Here is the relevant class `Player` for Google Play Games:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Player.html

And the relevant class `People` from Google Plus:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/package-summary.html

Finally, there is `AdvertisingIdClient` for the Google Mobile Ads platform:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient.html

Comment: Yes, I don't want to ask the user for G+ permissions. I just want the user ID. I don't know how to get to this "Player" class.

Comment: `com.google.android.gms.games.Player`
It's right on the first link.

Comment: So just import it and that's it? And I get the user's ID? Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: I notice that the player ID is a string, not an integer. What if the user didn't set a player string ID? I just want their user ID within Google Play Services....

Comment: Sounds like you want `AdvertisingIdClient`

Comment: I do not. It needs to be persistent, in order to track all of a user's acquisitions (eg: free levels given for getting other users to play my game). The user can clear and reset the AdvertisingIdClient.

Comment: Then `Player` _is_ what you want. To the best of my knowledge, it matches the account, and it is not user-set but tied to the google account.

Comment: Ok. So I know I need ``import com.google.android.gms.games.Player;`` and ``SOMETHING.getPlayerId();``.. can you tell me: what is SOMETHING???

Answer (score 2):

So the `Games.Players` class is deprecated and nobody gave a summarised solution to get the entire player object that allows to get the player ID, eventually. Here is what I've sorted out:

```
GoogleSignInAccount account;
PlayersClient playerClient;
Player player;
String playerId;

account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
if (account == null) {
    // do sign-in here
}

// Later:

playerClient = Games.getPlayersClient(this, account);
Task<Player> playerTask = playerClient.getCurrentPlayer();
player = playerTask.getResult();
if(player != null) {
    playerId = player.getPlayerId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the answers above our outdated. Try this:

```
var playerID = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.id
```