# Getting player ID after logging in to Google Play Game Services

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am able to log in using helper classes from BaseGameUtils: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils

How can I get the ID of the player just logged in?

```
gameHelper.setConnectOnStart(false);
gameHelper.setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(0);
gameHelper.setup(gameHelperListener);    
final GameHelper.GameHelperListener gameHelperListener = new GameHelper.GameHelperListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
        // I want to get the player ID here
    } 
};
```

Login code:

```
try {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
        }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: `Games.Players` is deprecated. Please check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413589/get-a-user-id-from-google-play-services/52593945#52593945

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was answered here:
[Get a user ID from Google Play Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413589/get-a-user-id-from-google-play-services)

Here is the solution:

```
String playerId = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId(getApiClient());
```